# Can't move a smart ptr into a std::function

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14, smart-pointers

I want to create an `std::function` that captures a `auto_ptr/unique_ptr` into but can't properly do it. I need a solution that works on c++11 but I couldn't even figure out how to do it on c++14

Following examples work with c++11 (`IncByTwenty`) abd c++14 (`IncByThirty`). However When I change those `auto` s to `Func`, it no longer compiles.

```
typedef std::function<int( int )> Func;
Func IncByTen = std::bind( []( const int& p, int t ) -> int
{
    return p + t;  
}, 10, std::placeholders::_1 );

std::unique_ptr< int > pTwenty(new int(20));
// should have work in c++11 i think? cant assign to Func type
auto IncByTwenty = std::bind( []( const std::unique_ptr< int >& p, int t ) -> int
{
    return ( *p ) + t;  
}, std::move( pTwenty ), std::placeholders::_1 );

std::unique_ptr< int > pThirty = std::make_unique< int >( 30 );
// c++14  cant assign to Func type
auto IncByThirty  = [p{std::move(pThirty) }]( int t ) -> int
{
    return ( *p ) + t;  
};

std::cout << IncByTen(3) << " "  << IncByTwenty(4) << " " << IncByThirty(5);
```

Am I doing it wrong? Otherwise I need to create something that is assignable to `std::function` and it needs to capture some local variables using move operator. Any suggestions?

Comment: Don't use `std::auto_ptr` in C++11.

Comment: I wanted to make example fully c++11. in reality I am using a inhouse `uniqe_ptr` implementation

Comment: How does `std::auto_ptr` make the example fully C++11? C++11 is when it was deprecated.

Comment: ah, I am dumb. editing post. I was confusing it with make_unique

Comment: @taytay no worries, sometimes people are confused since `std::make_unique` was only added to C++14

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Can't move a [`std::unique_ptr`] into a `std::function`

You cannot, because `std::unique_ptr` is not copyable. (otherwise it couldn't be unique). `std::function` requires the function object to be copyable.

There is a proposal to add a function wrapper for non-copyable (specifically, move-only) function objects: [P0228rX](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2019/p0228r3.html), but such proposal is not part of the language yet.

Answer (score 2):

Since a `std::function` is a copiable type erasure container, it can only contain copiable types.

The [`std::function` documentation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function/function) states that it requires this (`F` being the type sent to the constructor):

> ### Type requirements
>
> - `F` must meet the requirements of [*Callable*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/Callable) and [*CopyConstructible*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/CopyConstructible).
> - `Alloc` must meet the requirements of [*Allocator*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/Allocator).

Your lambda must be copiable to be contained in a `std::function`

You can use `std::shared_ptr` instead or simply use a non-owning pointer:

```
auto pThirty = std::make_unique<int>(30);

auto IncByThirty = [p = pThirty.get()](int t) -> int {
    return *p + t;  
};
```

However you must make sure that the pointed data lives as long as the lambda and all `std::function` containing it.

Comment: that was what I was afraid.in my actual case `IncByThirty` will outlive `pThirty` so that wouldn't work. i guess moving it to a shared ptr only way. thanks.

Comment: in my actual case `IncByThirty` outlives `pThirty ` though. imagine that code is in a function returns `IncByThirty`